# Does a changeling gain the abilities of the race it shapeshifts into?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, eberron, shapeshifting, changeling

If a changeling in D&D 5e shapechanges into a merfolk, would it get the abilities of the race, for example, the ability to breathe underwater? I have been wondering about this for ages, and haven't gotten a straight answer, because the race profile for the changeling doesn't talk about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### None of your game statistics change.

The changelings Shapechanger feature says:

> You can make yourself appear as a member of another race, though *none of your game statistics change.*

This means if you can’t breathe underwater, you can’t breathe underwater when you use Shapechanger.

Game statistics here refers to *everything mechanical about your character*. That is, all of your racial traits, class features, ability scores, everything. We see this explained for NPCs in the *Monster Manual*:

> A monster’s statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster.

But this applies to PCs as well - your statistics are everything that make you, well, you, within the calculus of the game rules. In the *Player’s Handbook*, we have reference to game statistics in the step by step character creation section:

> Your character is a combination of *game statistics*, roleplaying hooks, and your imagination.

Comment: @BenScott It may be worth noting that changelings have never gotten abilities from their innate shapechanger ability. The original write-up (for the “v.3.5 revised edition,” i.e. incompatible with modern rules) based the ability on *disguise self*, a 1st-level illusion spell, and not *alter self*, a 1st-level transmutation, to emphasize how it was appearance-only. They found it clearer to say “like *disguise self* except your appearance actually changes rather than being an illusion,” than to say “like *alter self* except you don’t gain any abilities or stats from it.”

Comment: In 4E there was a feat *Becomer* that allowed changelings to pick up minor racial features - skill proficiency and language - from a specific "favoured" target race. It would probably work translated to 5E as a homebrew.

Comment: eh. i found a homebrew that does what i want it. now to see if my dm will let me use it...